# Access value in condition statement in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Is it possible to access the value that is the result of a condition? For instance:

```
cond do
    Map.get(values, :foo) ->
        IO.puts "Value: #{foo}"
    true ->
        IO.puts "No value"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

```
cond do
  value = Map.get(map, :key) ->
    IO.puts "Value: #{inspect value}"
  true ->
    IO.puts "No value"
end
```

You will need to actually assign the value in order to use it.

Comment: Exactly, In elixir everything is a expression to tell the truth the test thing to do is to assign at the return of the `cond`. That if it was necessary to access the value outside as result

Answer (score 3):

You could also try `case` like:

```
case Map.get(map, :key) do
  nil ->
    IO.puts "No value"

  value ->
    IO.puts "Value: #{inspect value}"
end
```

Please check [this link](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html) if you want to learn more.

**EDIT**

This unfortunately is not accurate enough, as `value` related to `:key` might actually by `nil`. If you want to be sure if the `value` exists in `map`and only then use it, you could try [`Map.fetch/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#fetch/2):

```
map = %{key: nil}

case Map.fetch(map, :key) do
  {:ok, value} ->
    IO.puts "Value: #{inspect value}"

  :error ->
    IO.puts "No value"
end
```